# Android App. Multiple Buttons leading to the one Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android Programming and currently working on an app that saves schedules to be sent on a microcontroller. I made a grid layout of 21 text fields which will call the same activity containing all the text fields to be used. But it does not work. Any idea on how can I do this and organize the saved data to efficiently pass it over the microcontroller and how to call the same activity over again? Thank you so much in advance.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.slot1)
    {
        Intent intent_edit1 = new Intent(EnterInformation.this, EditInformation1.class);
        startActivity(intent_edit1);
        finish();
    }

    else if(v.getId() == R.id.slot2)
    {

        Intent intent_edit2 = new Intent(EnterInformation.this, EditInformation1.class); //edit
        startActivity(intent_edit2);
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.slot3)
    {
        Intent intent_edit3 = new Intent(EnterInformation.this, EditInformation1.class); //edit
        startActivity(intent_edit3);
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.slot4)
    {
        Intent intent_edit4 = new Intent(EnterInformation.this, EditInformation1.class); //edit
        startActivity(intent_edit4);
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.slot5)
    {
        Intent intent_edit5 = new Intent(EnterInformation.this, EditInformation1.class); //edit
        startActivity(intent_edit5);
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.slot6)
    {
        Intent intent_edit6 = new Intent(EnterInformation.this, EditInformation1.class); //edit
        startActivity(intent_edit6);
    }
```

This is what my layouts look like:
[Enter Pill Information (left) Edit Pill Information (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIScl.jpg)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: I already added some... thanks :)